# How to create new page url?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

I've created an index.phtml page and it work on myWeb.id/brand link. Now I create `edit.phtml` on my brand folder but I can't access it on `myWeb.id/brand/edit.phtml`. My web says 404 not found. What should I do?

**My module :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <myWeb_Brand>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </myWeb_Brand>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**my brand.xml :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>   
    <layout version="0.1.0">   
      <brand_index_index>   
        <reference name="root">   
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
        </reference>   
        <reference name="content">   
          <block type="brand/index" name="brand_index" template="brand/index.phtml"/>   
        </reference>   

    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template /></action>
        </reference>
      </brand_index_index> 



    </layout>
```

**my local block index.php**

```
<?php   
class myWeb_Brand_Block_Index extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {   
}
?>
```

**indexcontroller.php**

```
<?php
class myWeb_Brand_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {

      $this->loadLayout();   
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Brand"));
            $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
           ));

      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("brand", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Brand"),
                "title" => $this->__("Brand")
           ));

      $this->renderLayout(); 

    }

}
```

**Helper :**

```
<?php
class myWeb_Brand_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**Config.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <myWeb_Brand>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </myWeb_Brand>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <brand>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>myWeb_Brand</module>
            <frontName>brand</frontName>
          </args>
      </brand>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <brand>
              <file>brand.xml</file>
            </brand>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <brand>
        <class>myWeb_Brand_Helper</class>
      </brand>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <brand>
        <class>myWeb_Brand_Block</class>
      </brand>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Please update layout handle that you are using?

Comment: show us some code to help you out.

Comment: please check my codes @PrasantaHatui

Comment: I've added the codes @userpk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in **brand.xml**

```
<brand_index_edit>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="brand/edit" name="brand_edit" template="brand/edit.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </brand_index_edit>
```

add below code in **indexcontroller.php**

```
public function EditAction() {

  $this->loadLayout();   
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Brand"));
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
  $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
            "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
            "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
       ));

  $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("brand", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Brand"),
            "title" => $this->__("Brand")
       ));

  $this->renderLayout(); 

  }
```

And create block class Edit.php and put below code:

```
<?php   
class myWeb_Brand_Block_Edit extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {   
}
?>
```

Comment: Still 404 not found :(

Comment: yes, i'm using that link, but nothing happen.

and I'm trying to check by echo something on EditAction () but thats not work too

Comment: sorry use this url format **myWeb.id/brand/index/edit**

Comment: okay thanks it works, but can I make it to **myWeb.id/brand/edit** ?

Comment: You have to create url rewrite rule from backend

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<brand_index_edit>   
  <reference name="root">   
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
  </reference>   
  <reference name="content">   
    <block type="brand/edit" name="brand_edit" template="brand/edit.phtml"/>   
  </reference>   
</brand_index_edit>
```

in your url

```
www.yourwebsite.com/brand/edit/
```

Make sure you have Edit.php(Block File) and edit.phtml (Template File) placed Properly.

Comment: I follow your instruction to create Edit.php block file and my edit.phtml placed properly. But nothing happen. Still 404 not found

Comment: First check if its going to your edit controller action. If it does  then check if the block it getting called by printing something in _constructor. Then finally check if your phtml file is getting called.

Comment: should I create a new controller? I just have IndexAction() in my IndexController.php